# Form uploads image to 'media' folder when it should upload to 'static'

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I am using an EventForm to let user edit the event model.
In my model, I've specified the upload_to directory

```
class Event(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='event_image')
```

and I was expecting the Form that is linked to the model to upload it to the same location, but it is uploaded to media - the filename I got from obj.image.url is 'media/filename'. Here is my form:

```
class EventForm(forms.ModelForm):
    image = forms.ImageField(label="Event Image", required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Event
```

views.py:

```
def edit_event(request, event_id):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        edited_event = Event.objects.get(id=event_id)
        form = EventForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=edited_event)

        if form.is_valid():
            data = form.cleaned_data
            cat = Category.objects.get(name=data["category_str"])

          Event.objects.filter(id=event_id).update(name=data["name"],description=data["description"],address=data["address"],
                                                    volunteerLimit=data["volunteerLimit"],category=cat,minimumAge=data["minimumAge"],
                                                    image=data["image"], date=data['date'])
   return render(request, 'handsup/index.html')
```

Here are my setting for media and static roots:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATICFILES_DIRS = [STATIC_DIR, ]

MEDIA_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_ROOT = MEDIA_DIR
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

All of the model's images are uploaded to 'media/event_image', but modified images are uploaded to be 'media/filename' but it does not exist in that directory. What is the best way to fix this problem?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I'm confused when you say the following:

> I was expecting the Form that is linked to the model to upload it to
>   the same location.

If you save an instance of your model directly with that `ImageField`, then the file you saved should end up in your `MEDIA_ROOT`.

This is how Django's `FileField`s work by default: they do not send things to `STATIC_ROOT`.

Staticfiles are explicitly for site-content, not user-uploaded things.

You can't even set your `STATIC_ROOT` and `MEDIA_ROOT` to be the same directory, because they serve different purposes and Django's settings-checker will throw an error if so. [Here's that error in the code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/5411821e3b8d1427ee63a5914aed1088c04cc1ed/django/contrib/staticfiles/utils.py#L57):

```
if ((settings.MEDIA_ROOT and settings.STATIC_ROOT) and
            (settings.MEDIA_ROOT == settings.STATIC_ROOT)):
        raise ImproperlyConfigured("The MEDIA_ROOT and STATIC_ROOT "
                                   "settings must have different values")
```

I think a better question is: why are you creating a model that you want to use to store staticfiles?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. My own mistake there. I will modify my question. The problem is the image should be uploaded to 'media/event_image/filename', but it was not uploaded there and the object.image.url is 'media/filename' which does not exist.

Comment: Ah. I'm not sure how much help I'll be in that case. There is still something confusing, though: if the file is not uploaded to `media/event_image/filename` and the `object.image.url == media/filename`, which as you say "does not exist", it sounds like the image is in neither place. Where did it go? Is it getting uploaded at all?